# How can i await for my response - in my mock function in jest test

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am following this youtube video where he is explaining how we can mock async functions.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uo0psyTxgQM

between 18:00 and 18:30 is the part where he writes the test

I've done same things as he did and when i run my test

```
describe("App", () => {
  it("fetchImages", (done) => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
    setTimeout(() => {
      wrapper.update();
      expect(wrapper.find("Image").length).toEqual(1);
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

i get always error that there are 0 Image instances but i expect 1.
I debugged and saw with console log that my mock function is actuily hitted instead of the actual api,
with my fake data so because i have one object fake data there shold be one Image instance.

**fake data with the actula mock function**

```
const fakeData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    categories: [{ title: "something" }],
    user: {
      name: "some name",
    },
    links: {
      html: "some html",
    },
    urls: {
      small: "sdsdsd",
    },
    likes: 44,
  },
];
export default async (term) => {
  return await new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve(fakeData);
  });
};
```

i guess that there is some problem in the test - it does not await for the response to happen.I am using jest version

`26.6.3` and jest-enzyme `7.1.2`

How can i await for my response - in my mock function in my jest test ?

Comment: *I've done same things as he did* - please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem. The question should be comprehensible without navigating to external links. The use of `setTimeout` and `done` is a bad practice but it's expected to work in a scenario like that because it's slower than a promise.

Comment: Tnx for your response.I will make new question with the whole code then... btw can you recommend some links for learning - where is explained the right way to write test for use case like this ? Thanks in advance

Comment: The way that is currently widely adopted is React Testing Library, it has waitFor for such cases. Enzyme doesn't work well for functional components.

Comment: I know Estur.The project that i need to work on has enzyme.....They choosed enzyme in the past because of the shalloiw rendering option instead of full rendering of the components tree.Btw, i wonder does react testing library has option for shallow and full components tree rendering, or is it only full rendering by default ?

Comment: The strategy for shallow rendering is generic - just mock all comps you don't want to be rendered by means of Jest. See https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/faq/

Comment: Are you not missing the async reference on your it()? `it("fetchImages", async (done) => {`